# Endpoints usando Vraptor

Tags: java, rest, get, vraptor

Tô com um problema aqui mas não sei se dá p/ resolver .
Tenho um método que tem muitos parâmetros então eu fiz uma espécie de filtro, e ficou assim :

```
@Get("")
        public void findByFilter(Filtro filtro) {
    //faz algo
    }
```

a questão é que  em um aplicação ,Spring por exemplo, quando precisasse buscar algo por nome eu enviaria a seguinde URL : **localhost:8080/api?name=xxx**  mas usando Vraptor sou obrigado a usar: 
**localhost:8080/api?filtro.name=xxx** .

Minha dúvida é se existe uma forma de conseguir fazer com que o Vraptor entenda a URL como o Spring, e que meu Front-end não precise saber o nome da variável que escolhi para poder fazer uma requisição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você precisa definir no Get o que você deseja pegar, exemplo.

```
@Get("/{todo}")
public void getOne(Todo todo) {
    result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot()
          .from(todoRepository.find(todo.getId())).serialize();
}
```

OBS: Você não vai precisar usar QueryStrings, se por acaso isso for um requisito creio que você terá que passar parâmetro por parâmetro.

Refêrencia: 
http://www.vraptor.org/pt/cookbook/utilizando-angularjs-vraptor4/

Comment: Tinha lido esse tópico, infelizmente não condiz com a arquitetura do projeto que tô inserido, mas ajudou a entender como a ferramenta funciona, obrigado!